# PHP Echo bug or typo

Tags: php, html, echo

So I have this line:

```
echo '<option value="random" ' . 
      ($lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random") ? 'selected=selected' :
      false.'>Random</option>';
```

But on the output I get something like this:

```
<select>
   selected=selected
   <option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>
```

Why do I get this? Where is my typo/bug? Maybe you guys can see it?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way that code produced that output.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose your ternary expression (the entire thing) in parenthenses

```
echo '<option value="random" '.($lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random" ? 'selected=selected' : '').'>Random</option>';
```

Or separate the expressions with a comma (wich is an option with [`echo`](http://de.php.net/echo)):

```
echo '<option value="random" ', 
     $lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random" ? 'selected=selected' : '', 
     '>Random</option>'
    ;
```

[Codepad of the differences](http://codepad.org/YliMgalX)

What is currently happening with your statement is the equivalent of this:

```
$condition = '<option value="random" ' . ($lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random");
$t = 'selected=selected';
$f = false.'>Random</option>';
echo  $condition ? $t : $f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be braces around the ternary or the single quotes....

try this

```
echo '<option value="random" '.($lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random" ? "selected=selected" : "false") .'>Random</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

primarily your problem is that echo is a construct not a normal function.  You cant use your ternary operator in the echo statement.

try

```
 $SelectedValue = ($lol_settings->gallery_effect == "random") ? 'selected=selected' : ' ';
 echo '<option value="random" ' . $SelectedValue .'>Random</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating `false` with `'>Random</option>';`

It's therefore part of the string that is in the "else" portion of your `?:`